# how can i get the value of an input field in react without using the onchange method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, graphql, apollo

I'm using react for generating some items in a form. I can get the value via the `onchange()` function but when I do this and I pass to my backend the default value is not assigned. How can I make sure that this `defaultValue` is also send with the form.

I tried it with a submit form and getting the html elements but this does not work and is not the recommended way.

this is my code:

```
data.getChecklist.checklist_items.map((item, index) => {
    return <div>
        <p>ITEM: {item.info}</p> 

            <TextField
                name={`${index}`}
                required
                defaultValue ={item.default_text}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                label="text"
                fullWidth
                />
                {item.checklist_sub_items.map((subitem, subindex) => {
                    return<div>
                            <p>SUBITEM: {subitem.info}</p> 

                        <TextField
                                name={`${subindex}`}
                                required
                                defaultValue ={subitem.default_text}
                                onChange={(e) => handleChangeSubItem(e)}
                                label="text"
                                fullWidth
                            />
                    </div> 
            })} 
    </div>  
})
```

EDIT:
I want it to not use the `onchange()` function because the user does not always have to interact with the field.

Comment: "I don't want" vs "is not the recommended way" ... forgot react is data-driven ? ... use checklist to generate initial state - array of values (used to render form), use onChange to update array entries ... render [divs with] inputs using 'key' - you should have warnings in console

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the default value as an argument in onchange.

onChange={(e) => handleChangeSubItem(e, defaultValue )}

And later during submit you can create an object of current value or defaultValue or store defaultValue in another variable is total up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not what i am looking for. I want to pass the value without using the onchange function because the user does not always need to interact with this text field.